# Renaming image files with PyExifTool 0.5.4 (exiftool in python)

Tags: python, exiftool

I'm trying to rename jpg files from a python script with exiftool using PyExifTool 0.5.4.
I can change tags, e.g. DateTimeOriginal, but when I try to rename files using tags I can't get the correct formatting for the filename.

```
with exiftool.ExifToolHelper() as et:
    et.execute('-d %Y-%m.%%e', '-filename<DateTimeOriginal', os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

When called from python this code seems to ignore the format given with `-d` and simply renames files to the content of the DateTimeOriginal tag, e.g. `2021:12:25 16:26:37`. The same result is produced when I run it in a terminal without `'-d %Y-%m.%%e'`

Running the command from the terminal, e.g. `exiftool -d %Y%m.%%e '-filename<DateTimeOriginal' b.jpg` renames the file using YYYYmm as expected.

Answer (score 0):

dropf, your call to `execute()` is incorrect.  The parameter `'-d %Y-%m.%%e'` needs to be two different parameters to `ExifToolHelper.execute()`

```
with exiftool.ExifToolHelper() as et:
    et.execute('-d', '%Y-%m.%%e', '-filename<DateTimeOriginal', os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

This is the way that `execute()` works.  If you have an unquoted space on your command line to `exiftool`, then you need to pass it as another parameter.

FYI: you can also post an issue onto the [PyExifTool GitHub page](https://github.com/sylikc/pyexiftool/issues) if you have other issues